# Proving there exist a branch of $\log(f(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following homework question:

> Suppose that $$f\in H(D(z_{0},r))$$ and $f(z_{0})\neq0$. Prove that, for
>   some $\rho\in(0,r]$, there exists a function $g\in H(D(z_{0},\rho))$
>   s.t $$e^{g(z)}=f(z)$$ for all $z\in D(z_{0},\rho)$.

**My thoughts:**

I would like to use the following theorem:

> Let $G\subseteq\mathbb{C}$be open and connected then there exist a
>   branch of $\log(z)$ on $G$ if and only if:
>
> a. $0\not\in G$
>
> b. $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}\, dz=0$ for every closed $\gamma$ which
>   is piecewise $C^{1}$and s.t $trace(\gamma)\subseteq G$

I thought of denoting $G=f(D(z_{0},\rho))$ and then we have some
$g$ s.t for every $z\in(D(z_{0},\rho)$ 
$$
e^{g(f(z))}=f(z)
$$

and by denoting $h=g\circ f$ we get 
$$
e^{h(z)}=f(z)
$$

and $h$ is the required function.

But I am having difficulties proving that the assumptions of the theorem
I'm using holds.

1. $0\not\in G$ - Since $f$ does not vanish in $D(z_{0},\rho)$
2. $G$ is connected - since $f\in H(D(z_{0},r))$

It remains to prove $b$ and that $G$ is open.

If $f$ is not a constant then by the open mapping theorem we have
it that $G$ is open.

I don't know how to handle the case where $f$ is a constant, or how
to prove $b$.

Can someone please help me deal with the other cases, or suggest a
different approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to the continuity $f(z)$ at $z=z_0$, there exists a number $\rho$ s. t. $f(z)$ has no zeros in the disk $D(z_0,\rho)$.
For $z \in D(z_0,\rho)$ we define
$$g(z):=\int_{[z_0,z]} \frac {f'(t)} {f(t)} dt +\log f(z_0), 
$$ 
where the integration is done over the interval $[z_0,z]$ and the principal value of $\log f(z_0)$ is chosen. It is clear that $g \in H(D(z_0,\rho))$, being an integral of an analytic function. Next, the derivative of $$(e^{-g(z)}f(z))'=-e^{-g(z)}g'(z)f(z)+e^{-g(z)}f'(z)= e^{-g(z)}\left(-\frac {f'(z)} {f(z)}f(z)+f'(z)\right)=0$$ in $D(z_0,\rho)$. This implies $e^{-g(z)}f(z)=const$ there. The substitution $z=z_0$ implies $const=1$ and $f(z)=e^{g(z)}.$